# get product name, price, image url and specific other fields with an array of ids

Tags: products, sql, magento-1.4

I am not clear on this, but want to do a bare-bones query which would have everything at the time the query is made, not only the id and product type.  I have an array of entity_id values, and I only one specific columns in the fieldset.  Specifically, name, description, price, image URL and that's it.

How would I do this?  I am new enough to Magento to not understand this concept.  Here is a pseudo-code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$productIds = array(5, 22, 45, 75, 88);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
            ->addFields('name','description', .. etc.. 'imageUrl')
            ->load();

foreach($products as $idx=>$obj){
    $data = $obj->getData(); //and hopefully this data is there and we don't need to requery the database.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my updated answer

```
$productIds = array(5, 22, 45, 75, 88);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','description','price','small_image'))
            ->load();

foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getDescription();
    echo $product->getPrice();
    echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'small_image');
}
```

Comment: that does not work, it says `invalid method .. addAttributeToFilter`

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: my code is tested and working fine

Comment: my code worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$productIds = array(5, 22, 45, 75, 88);
foreach($productIds as $prodId){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId);
    $name = $product->getName();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $description = $product->getDescription();
    $smallDescription = $product->getSmallDescription();
    $image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'small_image');
}
```

Let me know if it worked!

---

V2 (as requested all loading at once):

```
$productIds = array(5, 22, 45, 75, 88);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','description','price','small_image'))->load();
foreach($products as $product){
    $name = $product->getName();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $description = $product->getDescription();
    $smallDescription = $product->getSmallDescription();
    $image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'small_image');
}
```

Comment: Paul, is there any way to `loadAll()` outside the loop so that all queries to the database are accomplished initially, instead of inside the loop?  I'm trying to improve performance, and for 70 products, `load()` seems impractical if in fact there's an SQL query or multiple queries for each product.

Comment: @OliverWilliams check the edition I made in my original post, V2 is what you want. Let me know if it works!